# getting runtime error in symbolicating crash using Process() in swift

Tags: swift, bash

I've a code that looks like below:

```
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    process.arguments = ["symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    process.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

but, I get this error

```
symbolicatecrash: line 14: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 15: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 16: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
symbolicatecrash: line 17: `use Cwd qw(realpath);'
```

Both, `symbolicate` script and `crash.crash` are present in the directory from where Swift executes current process. So, they are very well accessible to `Process()`.

What does this error mean and what could be a possible fix to this?

Comment: looks as if `symbolicatecrash` was a shell script with a number of errors in it. Could you please show the contents of it here?

Comment: Its an Apple script. If you've mac, you can find it here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`

Comment: Its a script written by "Apple".  not an "AppleScript"

Comment: I’m sorry, you’re right. However, it’s neither AppleScript nor Bash but a Perl script instead. So again, this is why your approach cannot work. I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysing the script you are referring to reveals that it is a Perl script.  However, you tell `Process` to run a shell script (`process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"`) which is why this cannot work.

It should work to set the `launchPath` to the path of the script like this:

```
process.launchPath = "/path/to/symbolicatecrash"
process.arguments = ["crash.crash"]
```

It is unnecessary to specify the interpreter to use (`/bin/bash` in your example, would be `/usr/bin/perl` in mine) if the script can be invoked directly from the commandline. In the case of `symbolicatecrash` the script is directly executable because it correctly specifies the interpreter in the “shebang” line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Comment: Its a script written by "Apple".